# Why is Flash required for all pages?

Tags: support

I am using IE8, and have Flash turned off by default (I enable it for specific sites that need it). When I was visiting a Stack Exchange site, I noticed that on all pages I get the request to run Flash. I can't see any need for Flash on the majority of pages.

Is this a data collection effort (Flash cookies?) or for something else?

I want to know so I can turn it on (if needed) or off to improve perf.

Comment: Not reproducible. Which Stack Exchange site have you visited?

Comment: I also don't see any SE sites listed in [Flash's stored content](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html).

Comment: Are you maybe confusing Flash with JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I responded to Jeff's answer, along with a screenshot that shows the issue in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

We don't use Flash, so I think you are mistaken.

The `chat.*` sites use Flash only to do a message beep, but that is specific to the chat sites.

Comment: Jeff,

Thanks for the response. I am not sure how to attach images to a comment/answer, but I have a repo screenshot of IE8 asking to load flash on this very page.

Comment: I am using to enter/return adding a paragraph mark, not submitting the comment form. 

I uploaded the screenshot to my facebook account. Please let me know if you can see it. If not, I can find another way to get it to you.

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1604710154099&set=a.1604710114098.87474.1126489601&ref=fbx_album